# Html there is space in my container i cant use

Tags: html, css

I have this website:

https://jochemveldman.github.io/Tinker-prototype/

The 3 input fields are 100% together. But as you see i does not spread the whole purple block.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: That’s because the `<form>` they’re in has a width of 70%.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: their container is 70% width, and 15% margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.containerinput {
    width: 70%;     // <--- Change this to 100%
    margin-left: 15%;     // <--- Remove this
    height: 40%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #A1177F;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

New CSS `.containerinput`:

```
.containerinput {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #A1177F;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form class="containerinput" action="/action_page.php">
  <p class="TekstBijInputContainer">Uw taxi van en naar de luchthaven, door heel Europa</p>
  <div class="flex">
    <input class="adresgegevens-opgeven" placeholder="Van" name="fname" type="text">
    <input class="adresgegevensnaar-opgeven" placeholder="Naar" name="fname" type="text">
    <input class="adresgegevensdatum" placeholder="Datum:" name="fname" type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.flex{
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all your `input` inside a parent container, and provide css accordingly.

Your HTML should look something like this:

```
<div class="input-container">
  <input class="adresgegevens-opgeven" type="text" placeholder="Van" name="fname">
  <input class="adresgegevensnaar-opgeven" type="text" placeholder="Naar" name="fname">
  <input class="adresgegevensdatum" type="text" placeholder="Datum:" name="fname">
</div>
```

And the css should be like:

```
.input-container {
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```